# Unable to save text config files in IIS7 on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, permissions

My experience has been (on older setups) that I can remote into a system, edit a text file (*.config, *.aspx, *.ashx, etc...) in Notepad and save it.

I am unable to do this on the new box.  I don't know whether it has to do with IIS7 or Windows 2008 or something entirely different.

How can I set things up to allow quick Notepad edits of files being served by IIS7?

(AFAIK, I have full permissions on the file.  It is not marked read-only.)

Using Notepad, when I try to save it says "Cannot create the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfile.config file.  Make sure that the path and name are correct."

Comment: What kind of error message are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

It's UAC kicking you down.  Non-elevated processes basically have no rights in the INETPub directory structure.

What we do on all our W2K8 boxes is install a folder on the desktop with 3 shortcuts in it - CMD (elevated), Explorer (Elevated) and ProcExplorer (Elevated).  Each admin then right clicks them and selects "Pin to Start Menu".

UAC is quite painful with access issues - the error messages are standard "Access Denied" errors rather than "UAC is preventing access" errors, which is confusing as all get out.  I don't know how many times I've logged on to a "broken" box where the admin has granted full rights to Everyone in an attempt to fix this w/o knowing it's UAC overriding the ACLs.

Notes: To get explorer to work as elevated, you need to edit the folder options and check "Launch folder windows in a separate process".  Or run this REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DisableThumbnailCache"=dword:00000001
"DontPrettyPath"=dword:00000001
"EnableBalloonTips"=dword:00000001
"FriendlyTree"=dword:00000001
"Hidden"=dword:00000001
"HideFileExt"=dword:00000000
"SeparateProcess"=dword:00000001
"ShowAttribCol"=dword:00000001
"ShowSuperHidden"=dword:00000001
"SuperHidden"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running Notepad as an elevated program ("Run as administrator").  This also applies to Vista and Win 7.